# CodeIgniter error retrieving value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to populate a form in CodeIgniter.

My model:

```
  public function retrieve_where($id) {

        return $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('funds');
        return $query->row();

    }
```

My controller:

```
public function edit($id) {

        $data['record'] = $this->funding_model->retrieve_where($id);


        $config = array(

            array(
                'field'=>"fn",
                'label'=>"Funder Name",
                'rules'=>'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>"at",
                'label'=>"Award Type",
                'rules'=>'required'
            )

        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

        if(!$this->form_validation->run($config)) {

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('funding/edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

        }
```

The first part of my view:

```
echo form_open('funding/add');

$fields = array(
    array("name"=>"on", "display_name" => "Opportunity Name"),
    array("name"=>"fn", "display_name" => "Funder Name", "value" => $record->funder_name),
    array("name"=>"cd", "display_name" => "Closing Date"),
    array("name"=>"di", "display_name" => "Deadline Info"),
    array("name"=>"at", "display_name" => "Award Type"),
    array("name"=>"ama", "display_name" => "Award Max"),
    array("name"=>"ami", "display_name" => "Award Min"),
    array("name"=>"budget", "display_name" => "Budget"),
    array("name"=>"summary", "display_name" => "Summary Info"),
    array("name"=>"website", "display_name" => "Website")
);
```

Which returns:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$funder_name

Filename: funding/edit.php

Line Number: 14
```

I don't understand the issue though, as funder_name is a column in my table funds. Any ideas?

Comment: Why two returns in your `retrieve_where()` function? You are never going to get to the last two lines of code in that function. Also, why do you have config in the middle of functions.  That is really poor programming practice. What line is line 14 of funding/edit.php?

Comment: @MikeBrant where should I put the config?

Comment: You can keep your validation rules array in the controller, but you can also put them in a config file. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return $this->db->where('id', $id);
```

You don't need the return on this;

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```